# Cannot create a new Android Project using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I recently updated my sdk version from 18 to 20.

I tried to create a new Android Application Project.
I filled up all the needed fields to create a new project but when I came to the last page of the creating a new Android Application Project, this appears:

"
This templates depends on the Android support library, which is either not installed, or the template depends on a more recent version than the one you have installed.

Required version: 8
Installed version: Not installed
"

Then it also displays this link.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

It also has two buttons:

1. Install/Upgrade
2. Check again

When I click the first button, it's not downloading, installing or upgrading any of my software. And this messages display to my Console:

```
[2012-07-15 21:55:08 - SDK Manager] Fetching https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
[2012-07-15 21:55:16 - SDK Manager] Fetched Add-ons List successfully
[2012-07-15 21:55:16 - SDK Manager] Fetching URL: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
[2012-07-15 21:55:37 - SDK Manager] Done loading packages.
[2012-07-15 21:55:37 - Android Compatibility JAR not found:] D:\Software\Eclipse\v4\android-support-v4.jar
```

The button two does not do anything at all.

I downloaded the compressed file 'android-sdk_r20-windows' and extracted it to my hard drive. I used it to download the following:

1. Android SDK Tools
2. Android SDK Platform-tools
3. SDK Platform API8
4. Google APIs 8

I don't understand what my problem is, my eclipse works properly when I still haven't updated it yet. Did I forget do download some required tools or something?

Please help me.

**Add:** My eclipse works fine when I imported my previous Android Applications (my app runs on my emulator), the only problem is that I can't create a new Android Application.

[image: Here's my screenshot.]

Comment: Did I understand you correctly if I say you do not have the newest ADT for Eclipse installed?

Comment: I think I have the latest.

    Android DDMS 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819
    Android Development Tools 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819
    Android Hierarchy Viewer 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819
    Android Traceview 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819

I looked at my Help - Install New Software - already installed - Installation History.

Comment: Here's my Eclipse version:

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: Have you installed the "Android Support Library" from "Extras"?

Comment: If your **required field** field is **blank**, then try the answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840424/android-eclipse-support-library-required-version-blank), especially the patch link provided by DogGuts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `SDK Manager.exe` within the Android SDK r20 that you downloaded. In the list of software, scroll down to Extras at the bottom, and choose Android Support Library.

[image]

Comment: I opened my SDK manager, but I'm not getting any packages from the Extras folder.

Comment: Do you have it set to show available packages? See the checkboxes in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, Updates/New and Installed are checked.

Different API levels show download options, the Extras folder is the only one that does not show.

Comment: And you don't happen to see it anywhere else in the list? It's a very long list.

Comment: Do you really only have API level 8 installed? You should have at least the latest one installed, which you'll be using to develop your app.

Comment: Yes. I only installed the API 8. So am I going to download the API 16? Then what will I do next?

Comment: After you install the stuff for API level 16 and the Android Support library, you'll create a new project in Eclipse. :)

Comment: Should I install all of those things from the API 16? Or the SDK Platform ony?

Comment: I didn't install anything. I just opened it again a while ago, and after clicking Install/Upgrade, I already made a new android project. I don't know what went wrong, but thanks.

Comment: I have recently installed Eclipse 2020-12 but cannot create a new android application. I get the same result as above - Required version: 8 Installed version: Not installed

Answer (score 24):

I struggled with this for about an hour today and it started working.  I think the key was to uninstall and reinstall the support library, then restart eclipse.

Note: I had to restart eclipse twice, after uninstalling the support library from within the SDK manager. Manually deleting the folder form terminal did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:
Open Android SDK Manager. In the list of software, scroll down to Extras at the bottom >> and choose Android Support Library >> Delete Package >> Delete complete restart eclipse

Step 2:
Open Android SDK Manager. In the list of software, scroll down to Extras at the bottom >> and choose Android Support Library >> InstallPackage >> Installl complete restart eclipse >> Done

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425730/how-to-create-an-project-with-adt-r20-without-including-the-android-support-libr).  This is strange but works.

Go the SDK_Folder/extra/android and rename the folder **compatibility** to **support**. After that, restart the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me:

1. Goto Help > check for updates > Select Android Tools Development and install it
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Eclipse asked me to update Android SDK Tool. I clicked on ok
4. Android SDK Manager opened and I selected the options to install and update.
5. After finishing, I restarted eclipse and created new android project.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the Android Support Library from Extras-Android support Library..Then install it again..later you will be able to create new projects

Answer (score 0):

Workaround that worked for me:
- Delete the support library from the SDK manager
- Create a new project & install the support library by clicking on "Install / Upgrade"

Answer (score 0):

In fact I think there is a bug with the Text icon creator. Every time i try this it does not create the project properly even after doing all the re-installs as suggested by the other posts.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on one machine, when logged on with an account with limited admin privileges. I had set up the proxy details in the SDK Manager options menu and set it to force http instead of https. The extras folder was coming up empty.

In the log I had a message saying that it failed to download "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml" as the file was not found. I then went to `tools->manage addon sites`, then under `user defined sites` I added the URL "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml" (Different from the file mentioned in the log but it seemed to work). When I exited that dialog it updated the list and the extras folder was now populated with items including the Android Support Library.

Answer (score -2):

i had some problem. So for resolve this problem I change folder tools (adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130911\sdk\tools) by http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip