# No longer able to create projects after upgrading to ADT v20

Tags: android, linux, adt

I recently updated my ADT to v20 and I'm having problems creating new projects now. I have installed the platform SDKs for API levels 8, 10 and 15, but when I try to create a project based on 2.3.3 and with minimum 2.2 SDK Eclipse says:

> This template depends on the Android Support library, which is either
>   not installed, or template depends on a more recent version than the
>   one you have installed

I had no problems with these SDKs when I was using an older version of ADT, but now it seems to be causing problems. I'm using Eclipse Indigo 2 on Ubuntu with ADT 20. I can't download resources from the SDK Manager because they're not available in my country, so I have to install components manually.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create a new Android Project using Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492585/cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

I a not sure about this perticular error but to download and install any coponant you can follow following link.[install android componant offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766713/android-download-the-android-sdk-components-for-offline-install/9403527#9403527)