# Cannot create a new android application on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am a beginner to android development,I have downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64 with android 4.2 and started the eclipse version(Android developer tools) provided with it.
But when I click finish after filling all the details in new android application dialog box,the finish button doesn't seem to respond at all.
At the first click on finish button an application is created but no java files in it and the dialog box stays still.At least the android 4.2 library is not in the `application.src` is also empty.

I'm working with Windows 7 64bit and JDK 1.6 64bit.
Any idea on solving this?

[image]

Comment: Have you added the android SDK in your eclipse?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which manual you are following to set up and where you got stuck exactly?

Comment: @Grishu - yeah,its already added to the eclipse.

Comment: @Appu - I used the adt bundle which comes with an eclipse version with it.SDK is integrated with it as a default.Android website says that there is no need to setup sdk as it is integrated in that version.So I was just going to create new android application from file->new->android application project

Comment: Are you providing the Project Build Target API level? Just click on Project and rightclick `Properties` & in Android tab select any `Project Build Target`. I think this is the issue only.

Comment: You might not have installed API 17.just check it and install packages by opening SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks Grishu,but it did'nt help.Tried that one and got the same blank application.

Comment: @MehulJoisar - I checked the SDK manager and it says that it is installed correctly.

Comment: @HeshithaHettihewa if my answer help you then kindly accept that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

http://www.chhitizbuchasia.com/articles/chhitiz/2011/02/Setup%20Android%20SDK%20With%20Eclipse.html

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

[Cannot create a new Android Project using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492585/cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse)

install android sdk manager

[image]

[image]

step1

[image]

step2
[image]

step3

[image]

install the following sdk to perform the application

Download ADT plugin

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Download

[image]

BASIC STEPS

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-one-stop-android-sdk-installer-you-always-wanted

Best [Jvm setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Janmejoy I followed that manual.But after clicking finish(Step 7) I get that blank application shown in the image.And the window doesn't close after clicking finish button.It stays still.

Comment: Adt is already added to the eclipse version which comes with the new adt package.No problem with that,I can get "create new android application project" window.But the problem is new application is not created.

Comment: yeah,I tried reinstalling all the packages too.but did'nt help.

Comment: did you try like that..if your sdk path is correct and you have installed the sdk manager too then if you follow the above step surely it will work

Comment: yeah I tried that.But I cant go after step2.After clicking finish on that window I get just that blank application shown in the image I attached.

Comment: I checked eclipse.ini and I found only
"JavaVersion=1.6"

Comment: Did you download the ADT Plugin

Comment: I used ADT bundle from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.The eclipse version provided with it comes with adt installed.

Comment: So you followed  Setting Up the ADT Bundle  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Comment: Try  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-one-stop-android-sdk-installer-you-always-wanted steps

Comment: k..wait for a minute let me help you out

Comment: step1: uninstall every thing..step2: oven eclipse only step3: go to help install new software ..there https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ put the above link and download

Comment: thanx @Janmejoy it solved after installing all the packages again even JDK.Thanx for your help...Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is not that much robust IDE.If nothing can solve your issue.try to restart Eclipse and your Computer.

and yes,before restarting just update the packages.

Go to SDK Manager, and install available updates for following packages.

Android SDK Tools

Android SDK Platform-tools

After updating,it will be look like this,

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mehul,I resatarted eclipse and machine several times.Updated the packages,Reinstalled them.but no good on doing those.

Answer (score 0):

I just got mine past this bug; hopefully yours will fix too?

On the screens with menus to select from, where one item is greyed (selected?) as default:
Deliberately click the item, to ACTUALLY select it (it turns dark blue or something).

Mine apparently got caught up on the "Make activity" (or whatever) page, and until I went back and assumed that the default had failed to select it, I was unable to choose finish (even though it clicked, looked as though it was going to do something, and then didn't go).