# I can't click the finish button it seemed to be like disabled or something

Tags: android, eclipse, button, eclipse-juno

I was starting to create an android application in Eclipse Juno. I filled out all the neccessary requirements but when I'm about to click the finish button, it won't work. I can click it though but it won't open a new android application workspace for me and I'm like stuck on it for hours. Can somebody tell me what to do? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot create a new android application on eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411189/cannot-create-a-new-android-application-on-eclipse)

Comment: "I was starting to create an android application in Eclipse Juno." Use Android Studio. Read the documentation. Save yourself the time.

Answer (score -3):

The version of your SDK it not compatible with the JDK. All you have to do is to install the last version of JDK by use of the tool manager of eclipse of by searching for JDK on google and then directly installing it.