# Android Eclipse Support Library: Required version blank

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have just downloaded and installed the latest ADT Bundle for Windows available from the Android Developer website. Following this, I installed all the packages in the SDK Manager, including the 'Android Support Library Rev. 18'. Finally, I installed the latest ADT through the 'Help > Install New Software...' menu in Eclipse.

I have strictly followed the following guide to create my first project:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

But by the last step, I arrive at an error, showing the Support Library revision I have installed, and a required version of -blank-:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CScNj.png (sorry, I can't post images yet)

I have checked through 'Window > Preference' that Eclipse is pointing to the right SDK directory. Mine contains the directories: add-ons, build-tools, docs, extras, platforms, platform-tools, samples, sources, system-images, temp, tools - I assume this is correct.

I have read elsewhere about moving files from \extras\android\compatibility to \extras\android\support, however I do not have the 'compatibility' directory. Additionally, my support folder contains the folders: samples, v4, v7, v13 - if that means anything (I assume the problem lies somewhere in here). I have installed the packages in the Android SDK Manager with admin privileges, and have tried creating an android project in Eclipse with admin privileges too.

Not sure where to go from here. Has anyone else experienced this error and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down-voted, I had the exact same problem (debian, eclipse kepler, latest ADT, latest 'everything' from the android sdk manager).  Reverting to an older version (as proposed by @andev) of the tools fixed/worked-around the above problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may temporarily downgrade to previous version: just download http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip and extract it to your "..Android\android-sdk\tools" folder.
It solved the problem in my case.

UPDATE:
As @DogGuts suggested, a better way is to download correct templates from [here](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=601490055000&name=activities.zip&token=0obRvNdQp4BWbe36Zshpy9lJLII:1379692929479) and replace files in "\Android\android-sdk\tools\templates\activities"

And the best solution is update SDK to 22.2.1 version :)

Comment: Thanks; fixed the exact same problem for me on debian wheezy/eclipse kepler.  Using (quite predictable) [link](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-linux.zip) instead.

Comment: See [@DogGut's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859559/873263) - OP should change accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this appears to be an actual bug in the SDK tools: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149
see [#55](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60149#c55) for a workaround without having to downgrade the SDK tools.

Comment: Excellent save mate. You saved me from taking a shotgun to my face