# Cant create new AndroidAplication Project

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries

yesterday I made a lot of updates, because I had problem with libraries and I fixed it, I was working with my old projects yesterday and everything looks right until today. I wanted create New Android Application Project. After last step I getting this window:
[image]

I looked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492585/cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse) topic and I deleted my Support library then re install but it didn't change anything. I tried Update eclipse, I find some sort of unimportant updates,I installed them but it didn't fix my problem too.

Comment: Did you update ADT plugin?

Comment: Yeah I tried like he did http://androidforum.com/topic/1455-how-to-update-adt-plugin-for-eclipse/ I get the message: "No updates were found"

Comment: I tried also find something new by Help-> Install new Software and pasting this link " https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" but I have updated everything

Comment: sry I didn't see this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is a Bug in latest release SDK 22.2 
revert to old SDK 22.

Remove Android SDk/tools folder contens
and replace them with SDK 22(old version)

Download link: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22-windows.zip

Reference link: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33872

Comment: welcome, it waste my 4 hours during work to figure this out :)

Comment: I know this pain, I lost 2 hours because of this problem today ;)

Answer (score 0):

Project -> clean and Project -> build your project.....and then try to run it...

Hope this will help you...