# Eclipse cannot start new Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to start a new android application, but when i click finish on the final form a progress bar flashes but nothing else happens.

Why is a new project not being created?

Comment: show your error Logs

Comment: @ZaferCelaloglu it did not give me an error log or crash message, it did nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try Restating Eclipse !!

If restarting doesn't work try accepted answer of [Cannot create a new Android Project using Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492585/cannot-create-a-new-android-project-using-eclipse)
 I think you similar problem .

Or Post Logs.